# Approximate ways of sampling from a joint distribution with multiple dimensions outside of trying to build a kernel density estimator?

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I am trying to sample from a multivariate distribution of hourly data (e.g., imagine price or temperature values for every hour of the day). I want to generate scenarios of price/temperature data that I can use downstream in some optimizations I'm performing. It's relatively easy for me to build 1D KDE estimates of the data for each individual hour and sample from each of those 1D KDE estimates. However, this is clearly not ideal because the joint PDF might not really be composed of independent distributions and thus may not be able to be factored into the distributions on the individual hours of the day.

I could try multidimensional KDE, but the data required to do so increases exponentially with dimension, and so I likely wouldn't be able to do this unless I can formulate the problem in a way where only a few hours matter (so that it's a 2D or 3D problem).

Are there any other approximate methods that I might try? I have thought about sampling from the 1D distributions in an "importance to the downstream optimization outcome" way first, and then doing a selective sampling of the other 1D distributions enforcing the sampling to be within some percentile value of the original sample. For example, let's say I have temperature and I happen to sample a T in hour 8 which is in the 80th percentile of temperatures for that day. I might then enforce that the samples coming out of the hour 7 and hour 9 distributions fall within the 70th-90th percentiles of their distributions (i.e. +/- 10% of what was sampled in the first distribution). However, this is clearly ad hoc and I would need to discover to what extent these relationships are approximately true in my own data. And I don't know if this type of approach has a known name or not either.

Comments on the above or additional thoughts? The distributions don't need to be perfect, but some rough degree of accuracy is required.

Comment: take a look at 'copula' approaches!

Comment: You asked about sampling from a joint distribution, but then talk about KDEs. Do you actually have the joint distribution you want to sample from (if so what is it)? Or, do you only have data, and you want to estimate the underlying distribution, then sample more synthetic data? In this case, could you describe the data in more detail? What kind of assumptions can you make?

Comment: @BenBolker, thank you for the comment. The term "copula" definitely leads me to some interesting resources.

Comment: @user20160, I do not actually have the joint distribution. I have some data for which I want to generate an estimate of the distribution and then sample from it randomly, the random samples being hopefully representative of what might happen in the future.

Comment: Treating this as a generic density estimation problem is probably not a good way to go, given the high dimensionality. Instead, you should try to exploit as much prior knowledge/assumptions as possible. It seems you'd want to look into time series models. However, it's hard to say more without a more detailed description of your data and what you're trying to do.